# Best way to send Spark dataframe as JSON body over HTTP POST

Tags: apache-spark, solr, apache-spark-sql, http-post

I have a `Spark dataframe` that I need to send as body of `HTTP POST` request. The storage system is `Apache Solr`. We are creating `Spark dataframe` by reading `Solr` collection. I can use `Jackson` library to create `JSON` and send it over `HTTP POST`. Also, dataframe may have millions of records so preferred way is to send them in `batches` over HTTP.

Below are the two approaches I can think.

- We can use `foreach`/`foreachPartition` operations of `Spark dataframe` and call `HTTP POST` which means that HTTP call will happen within each executor (If I am not wrong). Is this approach right? Also, it means if I have 3 `executors` then there will be 3 HTTP calls that we can make in parallel. Right? But opening and closing HTTP connection so many times, will it not cause issue?
- After getting the `Spark dataframe`, we can save it in some other `SOLR` collection (using Spark) and then data from that collection will be read to get the data in batches using `SOLR API` (using `rows, start` parameters), create JSON out of it and send it over HTTP request.

I would like to know which one of the above two approaches is preferred?

Comment: I think that the number of parallel executions depends on your core amount. So if you have 3 executors with 4 cores each and you are not using threads in your program, so Spark will call 12 HTTP POST in parallel. About the connection object, maybe is not a good practice to use it inside foreach. Instead, you could use it in foreachPartition, if you have a few number of partitions.

Comment: just out of curiosity, why do you want to send such huge data via HTTP channel. right approach for this is to plugin some middleware like Kafka or Some MQ model for the downstream to subscribe.

Answer (score 0):

> After getting the Spark dataframe, we can save it in some other SOLR
>   collection (using Spark) and then data from that collection will be
>   read to get the data in batches using SOLR API (using rows, start
>   parameters), create JSON out of it and send it over HTTP request.

out of your 2 approaches 2nd approach is best since you have paging feature in solrj
1) save your dataframe as solr documents with indexes
2) use [solrj](https://www.baeldung.com/apache-solrj) is api which will interact with your solr collections and will return solr documents based on your criteria.
3) you can convert them in to json using any parser and present in uis or user queries.

Infact this is not new approach, people who are using hbase with solr will do in the same way (since querying from hbase is really slow compared to querying from solr collections), where each hbase table is solr collection and can be queried via [solrj](https://www.baeldung.com/apache-solrj) and present to dashborads like angular js.

more illustrative diagram like below..

[image]